# Autoupdate case scheduled flow after 5 days

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I have a schedule triggered flow that should look at the last modified date of the case  and if it is less or equal 5 days ago set the case back to open.
At first it worked great and debug without rollback.
Now since it runs daily it updates every case regardless of equal or less than 5 days.
Also I don´t know why the there is a warning because I put some filters in it so it shouldn´t look at ALL cases (DML limit and so):
Schedule is set to run daily at 5 AM
PS: The task object is only there to document the reopening. Works at least as it should.

Any ideas?
Kind regards

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you update the case to Open, you'll change LastModifiedDate to `NOW()` and hence the Case will get included again

Comment: @copredy Thanks but why? The filter should look on the last modified date -5 days.
If it get changed to NOW why is it valid for the filter?